# JS вычисление даты и времени

Tags: дата, javascript

Всем доброго времени суток. Вопрос следующий: есть переменная, содержащая дату в следующем формате: var start = "19.02.2015 14:00"; Необходимо получить дату и время например через 13 часов. То есть на выходе должно получиться что-то вроде "20.02.2015 03:00". Как я понимаю, необходимо использовать объект Date, но на этом мои познания заканчиваются, поэтому прошу помощи.
Заранее спасибо всем ответившим!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var match = '2011.07.15 13:18:52'.match(/^(\d+).(\d+).(\d+) (\d+)\:(\d+)\:(\d+)$/);
var date = new Date(match[1], match[2] - 1, match[3], match[4], match[5], match[6]);
var dateintime = date.getTime();
var result = dateintime + 46800000; // милиекунд в 13 часах
var resdate = new Date(result);
```

ну поскольку у вас дата в немного другом формате поменять индексы надо будет

Comment: премного благодарен!